# can't get result from total footerData in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm creating `jqgrid` dynamically, but have a problem. By creating footer `jqgrid`, I want total column 'get' ; but it doesn't  show any results.
 [image: see error pic]

How can I solve this problem?

this my code

```
  loadComplete: function () {

                var $self = $(this),
                       sum = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "get", false, "sum");

                $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", { get: sum });

            },
```

this json data

```
     data:
          [
            {ID:'1', get: 15 },
            { ID: '2', get: 585 },
           { ID: '3', get: 585 }
      ]

 colModel:
     [
     { ID: 'ID' IsForce: 'False', FieldType: Integer'},
      { ID: 'get'  FieldType: 'Integer'  }
  ]
```

Comment: Please provide **the demo**, which reproduces the problem, which you report. The `colModel`, which included to your question, seems to have no relation to jqGrid and contains syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the demo, to reproduce your problem and found the bug in `footerData`, which exists only in RTL languages. I posted [the corresponding fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/bf5c3e94f9fa973613f519dede97f1ec75551915) to GitHub. The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/144/ loads the latest version of free jqGrid from GitHub (the fixed version) and you can verify that the problem is fixed.

I plan to publish version 4.15.3 recently (probably during the next weekend). After that it will be available on CDN. Till the time you will have to download the free jqGrid from GitHub.

Comment: thanks but iam add   <script src="/grid.locale-fa.js"></script> dont show result

Comment: @saeed3164: The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/144/ loads https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.2/i18n/min/grid.locale-fa.js and is works. You should verify the path (URL) and the version of `grid.locale-fa.js`, which you use and the version of `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` (https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js)

Comment: thanks The problem I noticed now this https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/144/ when add new record then remove  new record ..dont remove

Comment: @saeed3164: Thanks for the demo. I see the problem with event bindings on new added rows in `formatter: "actions"`. I'll examine and fix the problem. I'll contact you after I'll post the fixed version to GitHub. One can still use Delete button of `navGrid`. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/145/.

Comment: @saeed3164: I posted [the fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/28aa8604f344b4813277cfd955253321f4bb62ba) to GitHub. Now your previous demo should work because it loads the latest code from GitHub.

Comment: thnaks but   you dont add lib jquery.fmatter.js to refrence demo

Comment: @saeed3164: all modules of jqGrid will combined in `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` and minimized to `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`. Thus one should almost always include `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` or for debugging `jquery.jqgrid.src.js`, but never `jquery.fmatter.js`. You can see in [commit list](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commits/master) that I rebuild `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` and `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` on every changes of any module. Thus you should just use the latest `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` from [GitHub download](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/archive/master.zip) and use in your project.